# Problems referring to a nested type of type as argument of a class template

Tags: c++, g++

I have a class template which defines a type inside it:

```
#include <boost/array.hpp>

template <typename T, int N>
class MyFunct {
public:
  typedef boost::array<T,N> FArray;
  MyFunct();
};
```

Now I have another class template. The thing that makes this class particular is that it is supposed to work only with types that define, inside of them, a type called `FArray`. Do not ask why please, there is a reason for this.

```
template <typename F>
class MyClass {
public:
  MyClass() {
    F::FArray a = F::FArray();
  }
};
```

And I use this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  MyClass< MyFunct<double,10> > m;
}
```

When I have this situation the compiler gets mad telling me that `double` has no member called `FArray`. What's happening?

Comment: I voted for close... I searched among questions but did not find the one reported now... I am sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `typename` here:

```
typename F::FArray a = typename F::Array();
```

Comment: Now it tells me that `double` is not a class struct or union type...

Comment: http://codepad.org/IgZCjWB8

Comment: @Andry it could be due to other errors, like the typos in the code sample you posted.

Answer (score 1):

Sloppy coding. Plus, g++ 4.7 says explicitly:

> test.cpp:14:9: error: need ‘typename’ before ‘F:: FArray’ because ‘F’ is a dependent scope

And the following compiles OK.

```
#include <boost/array.hpp>

template <typename T, int N>
class MyFunct {
    public:
          typedef boost::array<T,N> FArray;
              MyFunct();
};

template <typename F>
class MyClass {
    public:
        MyClass() {
            typename F::FArray a = typename F::FArray();
        }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
      MyClass< MyFunct<double, 2> > m;
}
```